# AWS S3 triggers Lambda with partial object key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I get the following trigger event for some of the files that are uploaded to a location s3://bucket/folder1:

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "eventVersion": "2.1",
            "eventSource": "aws:s3",
            "awsRegion": "eu-west-3",
            "eventTime": "2022-07-26T08: 30: 03.280Z",
            "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
            "userIdentity": {
                "principalId": "principalId"
            },
            "requestParameters": {
                "sourceIPAddress": "sourceIPAddress"
            },
            "responseElements": {
                "x-amz-request-id": "JZJMKZAYX3HMQTY8",
                "x-amz-id-2": "iXfsgUn5v1SQuR+YAacurX2qP+B7f39StWcWEyebkDbJzZzazygE9tABlKpg5hcW6lNOqZgEQ2jupDb26T9dww8fTG1O2Q0l"
            },
            "s3": {
                "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
                "configurationId": "NjViZmRiNmQtMTM0NS00NGZmLThlYjgtYjc4YWE4MWE2ZGU3",
                "bucket": {
                    "name": "bucket",
                    "ownerIdentity": {
                        "principalId": "principalId"
                    },
                    "arn": "arn:aws:s3: : :bucket"
                },
                "object": {
                    "key": "folder1/",
                    "size": 0,
                    "eTag": "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e",
                    "versionId": "qsENjqz.CmAFvvRg4z0.8ug4K0rZmegS",
                    "sequencer": "0062DFA60B3BF1F737"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that the key contains **only prefix without file name**.

Partial keys lead to 404 errors in the Lambda function:

```
event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]    

[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found
```

For the files I upload via S3 CLI, the object key is correct: folder1/file1.txt. How does it happen that I receive some 'object keys' without filenames?

Answer (score 0):

The event

```
                    "key": "folder1/",
                    "size": 0,
```

means that someone literally created an object called `"folder1/"` with size `0`. One way this happens is if you use S3 Console and use **Create folder** button in the console.

Comment: Interesting. Lambda errors out with this regularly, and the process is automatic

Comment: What lines in the Lambda function generate the error? Please Edit your question to show us the code and the _exact_ error message.

Comment: Updated. 404 error due to fetching non-existing object by its key